# Using 'too' as 'certainly'

Tags: word-usage

> I'm not going to school today.
>
> -You are too!

Assuming the above is correct English, how would you refer to this particular usage of "too"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an adverb. It functions as "an emphatic affirmative to contradict a negative statement." [[see Random House definition number 4]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/too). It is a usage it shares with "indeed" except that "too" is colloquial.

And I would write your sentence without a comma, because it is so short. (Edit, I see you have removed the comma.)

Anyway, I would also write the following sentences without a comma:

You are indeed!
You are indeed going to school!
You are too going to school! ==> This one sounds especially colloquial.

Another example:

You are not eating ice cream after dinner.

--I am too!

Notice "too" here does not mean "also," as in the following:

I'm eating ice cream after dinner.

--I am too!

Comment: I think quite a few of us would also include ***so*** as a possible (also colloquial, with a certain air of "childishness") alternative to ***too*** in such usages. And for a *really* colloquial alternative that I feel has less "childish" connotations, there's also ***and all*** in *some* contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is this

> I'm not going to school today.
>
> You are too **!**

Without the exclamation it would be understood as

> You are also.

ESN requested more explanation.

```
You are too!
```

`too` is this context is synonymous with saying `You are so!`

> I didn't eat it!
>
> You did so!
>
> NO, I didn't!
>
> You did too!

This isn't to say that every instance of the word `too` followed by an exclamation mark is understood this way.

It's a colloquialism developed by children at some point in time, not sure when, where, or even why, but the trend stuck and now it is part of our everyday speech.

When `too` is used in this way, it is meant to emphasize that the defendant did in fact do it (whatever it is), or at least that's what the accuser believes.  My point being: This can also be used to lie as well.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. What are the meaning and part of speech of *too* when used with the exclamation?